# python mmap skipping every second byte when writing

Tags: python, python-2.7, mmap

I have a strange problem with using mmap in python when writing to memory (/dev/mem).
To be clear, reading is done in the same manner and it works OK.
But when it comes to writing, it seems that every second byte is unwritable.

ex.

```
 when I read i get 
 addr 0x200 val 0x1234
 but when I try to write
 addr 0x200 val 0x4321
 what really is written is
 addr 0x200 val 0x0021
```

When I try to write byte by byte, the same happens.
ex.

```
write:
addr 0x200 0x43
addr 0x201 0x21
I get
addr 0x200 0x00
addr 0x201 0x21
```

Code:

```
class Pydump:
    def __init__(self, addr, length = 1, word_size = 4, filename = '/dev/mem'):
        if addr < 0 or length < 0: raise ValueError('Address or length invalid')
        self._verbose = verbose

        self.word_size = word_size
        self.mask = ~(self.word_size - 1)
        self.base_addr = addr & ~(mmap.PAGESIZE - 1)
        self.addr_offset = addr - self.base_addr
        self.word_length = length
        self.no_of_bytes = self.word_length * self.word_size

        # align length to full words
        end_addr = addr + self.no_of_bytes
        if end_addr % self.mask:
            end_addr = (end_addr + self.word_size) & self.mask

        self.map_length = end_addr - self.base_addr
        self.fname = filename

        self.fd = os.open(self.fname, os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
        self.mem = mmap.mmap(self.fd, self.map_length, mmap.MAP_SHARED,
                             mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE,
                             offset=self.base_addr)

    def read(self):
        mem = self.mem
        virt_base_addr = self.addr_offset & self.mask
        mem.seek(virt_base_addr)

        data = []
        for i in range(self.no_of_bytes):
            data.append(struct.unpack('B', mem.read_byte())[0])

        abs_addr = self.base_addr + virt_base_addr
        return PydumpBuffer(abs_addr, data, self.word_size)

    def write(self, data):
        mem = self.mem
        virt_base_addr = self.addr_offset & self.mask
        mem.seek(virt_base_addr)

        if self.word_size == 1:
            mem.write(struct.pack('B', data))
        elif self.word_size == 2:
            mem.write(struct.pack('H', data))
        elif self.word_size == 4:
            mem.write(struct.pack('I', data))
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid word size')

    def write_bytes(self, bytes):
        if len(bytes) != self.no_of_bytes: raise ValueError('Wrong number of bytes given')
        mem = self.mem
        virt_base_addr = self.addr_offset & self.mask
        mem.seek(virt_base_addr)

        for byte in bytes:
            mem.write_byte(byte)
```

Example run (I prepared the memory with other memdump tool [bin] to be 0xEEEEEEEE):

```
>>> from pydump import Pydump as memdump
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).read()
0xEEEEEEEE
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).write(0x12345678)
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).read()
0x00340078
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).write(0x87654321)
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).read()
0x00650021
```

Example no 2 (I could not write even 2 bytes at 'first' byte place):

```
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 2).write(0xABCD)
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).read()
0x00650021
>>> memdump(0x18007C21, 1, 1).write(0xCD)
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).read()
0x00650021
>>> memdump(0x18007C22, 1, 1).write(0xCD)
>>> memdump(0x18007C20, 1, 4).read()
0x00CDCD00
```

Any thoughts on what could be the problem ?

Comment: What Python version are you using? BTW, `bytes` is not a good variable name as it shadows the built-in [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) type. Note that in Python 2 `bytes` is essentially a synonym for `str`.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.10.

Comment: What is this memory that you're writing to? Is it a memory-mapped device? They could have special requirements and thus you could try ctypes for writing there.

Comment: Yes, it's memory-mapped device. Actually those are registers mapped to memory. How ctypes would be better if all I want is write specific words ?

Comment: Just a wild guess: you may have to write a word at a time, on word-aligned addresses. Is your CPU 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Hmmm can't reproduce.  Could any other process be accessing this memory.  Possibly zero-ing it before you read it to check your write has succeeded?  I'm assuming you get no errors with any of your methods?

Comment: Add a more complete code sample. Your write code is fragmentary and we can't see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Updated with full snipped (without PydumpBuffer which is for printing) and example runs. Yes this memory can be accessed by other process, but it's not. When I'm using memdump written in C it works OK. CPU is 64 bit.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I can't reproduce this issue even using your exact code (but obviously on an arbitrary portion of memory as I haven't got your memory mapped device).  Therefore my thoughts are it's either to do with the device, another process (although I take your comment above that nothing else is accessing that memory), or your specific hardware (although again I take your point that it worked in C, so unlikely to be hardware / OS specific)

Comment: BTW, you should know, every `Pydump` you create is leaking a file descriptor. You need to os.close the file descriptor after using it to create the mmap (which is perfectly legal; the mmap is independent of the fd once created, it keeps working even if the fd is closed).

Comment: Also, side-note: Is there a reason you're using `mmap` as a file-like object, instead of as a plain memory buffer? You can read from an `mmap` by slicing it (so `mymmap.seek(10); x = mymmap.read(4)` is a slow equivalent to `x = mymmap[10:14]`); the whole point of `mmap` is to get you a `bytes`-like object; if you're going to use it as a file-like object, no real point to using `mmap`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I close the descriptor in `__del__`.
I'm using seek, probably because I'm rewriting the C implementation :D
I wanted it to work, then refactor.

Comment: FYI, `if end_addr % self.mask:` is almost certainly wrong, but you may be getting lucky and avoiding the issue by chance. When you do `self.mask =  ~(self.word_size - 1)` in Python, it's not actually creating an unsigned value the way you might expect in C (`~(4 - 1) == -4` in Python, not `0xfffffffffffffffc` or `0xfffffffc` like it would in C). Negative numbers act the way you'd expect from `unsigned` types in C when used with bitwise operators, but for general math, they act like signed values, so `%` will not behave properly. I think you really wanted `if end_addr & self.mask:` anyway.

Comment: @k3tchup: But a C implementation using `mmap` wouldn't seek, unless you mean in C you're using pointer arithmetic? In any event, you can skip the `os.close` in `__del__` (removing limits on how many `Pydump`s you can create at once and improving behavior on non-CPython interpreters) by `os.close`-ing as soon as you finish `mmap`ing; no need to defer cleanup when you don't need the fd again.

Comment: Also, to be sure it's not an output issue, it would probably help to have the implementation of `PydumpBuffer`; if `PydumpBuffer` is wrong, then your output can't be trusted. I'm guessing this isn't an x86 machine? If it was, you'd expect to see the bytes reversed when you write a word them in native (little) endianness, then read it back in byte by byte, but you're writing them out in order.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Pydump buffer is certainly right, as I said C implementation gives the same output from reading after writing. And Pydumpbuffer is not used when writing.
Are you sayng I can close file descriptor just after creating mmap ?
BTW. I tried the slices and still the same problem.

Comment: @k3tchup: Yes, you can just close the fd the very next line after creating the mapping. `mmap` uses the fd to _create_ the mapping, but not after that (nothing you do to the fd will affect the mapping unless it affects the data being mapped); it's good practice (in both C and Python) to close the fd as soon as you no longer need it (because mmap is only limited by virtual address space, but many systems have fairly low maximum open file descriptor limits).

Comment: @ShadowRanger but if file descriptor will be closed, will mmap be able to write to already mapped memory ?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, the standard pattern is open fd, map memory, close fd, use memory. There is _no_ dependency between the fd and the mapping after the mapping is created. Beyond that, I suspect your problem is related to synchronization, but really have no way to tell; we can't reproduce your problem, and it sounds an awful lot like an issue with the device in question having finicky access patterns.

Comment: @k3tchup All the stuff @ShadowRanger stuff says is useful and should be taken account of.  However, I'm intrigued you say this worked in C, but not in Python and I can't reproduce the failure in Python.  This points to the device, but it worked in C.  So - maybe you could look at the implementation of Python's `mmap.write()` in C [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9a87023db3ed6a3bde316b6527d3eafb014c2c89/Modules/mmapmodule.c#L387) and see how it differs from your C implementation (if at all). That might give you / us a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what is wrong now.
The answer is that it's fault as well of python as my specific hardware/driver.

I looked through the implementation of mmap and it uses **memcpy**, which as we know copies byte by byte. In C implemention this did not happen, when we needed to write 4 bytes, 4 bytes were written.
So here comes the limitation of my hardware/driver which is that every register must be written in full (I did not know this at the time of stating the question), thus when writing byte by byte I will get weird behaviour.

Some registers are 16bit and some are 32bit.
When I was writing 0xFFFF to 16bit register I ended up having 0x00FF. So memcpy was copying 0xFF twice. My driver got write(0xFF) then write(0xFF), so what I was actually doing (because of the python) was two writes to register of byte 0xFF :)
Probably the same happened with 32bit registers, although it looked different (but also the driver may behave different).

For it to work I would have to change the implementation of python mmap :(